Autocomplete WooCommerce paid orders for specific payment gateway
I use WordPress with Woodmart theme and I want automatic orders to be completed.
I installed the codesnippets plugin and copied the following code from the codesnippet website:
But the order that was previously processing is not completed!
What should I put the payment method where it says "Change the Payment Method"?
Autocompleted WooCommerce order based on the payment method "Moneris Gateway"
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'ts_auto_complete_by_payment_method');
 function ts_auto_complete_by_payment_method($order_id)
{
 
  if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
   }
  global $product;
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
 
  if ($order->data['status'] == 'processing') {
        $payment_method=$order->get_payment_method();
        if ($payment_method!="cod") // Change the Payment Method
        {
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }

  }

}


When using WC Moneris Payment Gateway in WooCommerce the payment ID defined for Moneris Payment Gateway is simply: moneris.
This can be found on includes/class-wpheka-gateway-moneris.php plugin file (line 30): $this->id = 'moneris';
Now, based on How to autocomplete paid orders in WooCommerce? answer code, Here is the right way to autocomplete orders Paid through Moneris Payment Gateway:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'wc_auto_complete_paid_order', 10, 3 );
function wc_auto_complete_paid_order( $status, $order_id, $order ) {
    if ( $order->get_payment_method() === 'moneris' ) {
        $status = 'completed';
    }
    return $status;
}

Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Thank you very much for your time
I did it but the previous order is still Processing!
Does this code not work for previous orders? ... only the orders after this will be automatically confirmed?
Or did it not work at all?
Warm Regards.
